# I am having a conflict error between eslint configuation and base configuration when running a react project in development

Tags: reactjs, plugins, eslint

I am trying to run a react project in development but I got the following error:

`Plugin "react" was conflicted between "../.eslintrc.json" and "BaseConfig » /home/crudengr/Documents/projects/***/***/web-app/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js".`

The above error did not allow the page to load.
I noticed that whenever I save any js file I get this error but whenever I save in package.json file the error disappears and the page loads successful.

**.eslintrc.json** file

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 8,
      "requireConfigFile": false,
      "ecmaFeatures": {
          "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
          "jsx": true,
          "spread": true
      },
      "sourceType": "module",
      "babelOptions": {
          "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
       }
  },
  "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "jquery": true,
      "es6": true,
      "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": [
      "react",
      "jsx-a11y"
  ],
  "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
      "describe" :true,
      "context" :true,
      "before" :true,
      "beforeEach" :true,
      "after" :true,
      "afterEach" :true,
      "it" :true,
      "expect" :true,
      "workbox" :true,
      "importScripts" :true
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "rules": {
      "no-fallthrough": "error",
      "no-unreachable": "error",
      "no-cond-assign": "error",
      "valid-typeof": "error",
      "no-func-assign": "error",
      "no-extra-semi": "error",
      "linebreak-style": [
          "error",
          "UNIX"
      ],
      "no-unused-vars": "error",
      "no-console": "off",
      "no-undef": "error",
      "no-empty": "error",
      "no-case-declarations": "error",
      "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "error",
      "no-useless-escape": "error",
      "prettier/prettier": "error",
      "react/jsx-no-undef": "error",
      "react/jsx-no-bind": [
          "error",
          {
              "allowArrowFunctions": true,
              "allowBind": false,
              "ignoreRefs": false
          }
      ],
      "react/no-children-prop": "error",
      "react/no-deprecated": "error",
      "react/boolean-prop-naming": "error",
      "react/no-is-mounted": "error",
      "react/no-find-dom-node": "error",
      "react/no-did-update-set-state": "error",
      "react/no-unknown-property": "error",
      "react/no-unused-prop-types": "error",
      "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": "error",
      "react/no-unused-state": "error",
      "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
      "react/prop-types": "error",
      "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "error",
      "react/no-string-refs": "error",
      "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": [
          0
      ],
      "react/no-unescaped-entities": "error",
      "react/display-name": "error",
      "react/jsx-pascal-case": "error",
      "array-callback-return": "error",
      "no-loop-func": "error",
      "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "error",
      "prefer-const": [
          "error",
          {
              "destructuring": "any",
              "ignoreReadBeforeAssign": false
          }
      ],
      "no-var": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
      "react": {
          "version": "16.5"
      }
  }
}
```

**/node_modules/eslint-config-react-app/base.js** file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',

  plugins: ['react'],

  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
  },

  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    requireConfigFile: false,
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/prod')],
    },
  },

  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },

  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'warn',
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'warn',
  },
};
```

In my package json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.5",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2"
  }
```

node version: 17
npm version: 8
OS type: Ubuntu Linux

Any fix for the above error will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your folder "Documents" to "documents".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I renamed the folder "Documents" to "documents" but still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue and I just changed the root directory folder to all lowercase and it fixed my issue. So, I thought you had the same issue. If your issue isn't yet fixed, please try renaming all your directory folder name to all lowercase. I'm not sure if it will work for you. But, you may try.

Answer (score 0):

Because create-react-app is pulling in the react eslint plugin, you shouldn't need it in your package.json config. Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep names of all the directories (including your react-app directory) in all lowercase. Hopefully it will solve your problem.